# How does keras train without disrupting the data set order

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, machine-learning-model

I want to train a neural network using keras.

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=400, epochs=1000,shuffle=False)
```

I want the model training using the sequence of original data set order, not shuffle.

Comment: That's what 'shuffle=False' is for - could you give us some more detail about what you've tried and what's not working?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. when set shuffle=False,  the train will using the  original data set order? I thought it will disrupt the orginal dataset, but what disrupt will same in every epoch. When set shuffle=true, the disrupt will different in every epoch.

Comment: I find 'shuffle=False' is for it, not like what I thought.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Keras will shuffle training data before each epoch ([shuffle=True](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L182)).

If you would like to retain the ordering of your dataset, then set shuffle=False (docs [here](https://keras.io/models/model/)).